# Android - how to make a receiver that receive PHONE_STATE stay working even if the user closed the app

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am making android app and the app will do something when the android device get a call, but I want the app to keep listening for a call even if the user closed the app.

part of the `Manifest` file:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneState.PhoneStateHandler" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

`PhoneStateListener.java` file:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public abstract class PhoneStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

        onCallStateChanged(context, state);
    }

    protected abstract void onIncomingCallStarted(Context context);

    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
            onIncomingCallStarted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

`PhoneStateHandler` file:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class PhoneStateHandler extends PhoneStateListener{

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context context) {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

So how do I make the app listen for calls in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service for keeping it alive:

1) This is for starting the service Should be called on apps *onCreate()*:

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(service);
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.stopService(service);
```

2) The Service Class

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
 private static BroadcastReceiver m_ScreenOffReceiver;

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
 {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate()
 {
  registerScreenOffReceiver();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy()
 {
  unregisterReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver);
  m_ScreenOffReceiver = null;
 }

 private void registerScreenOffReceiver()
 {
  m_ScreenOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
     // do something, e.g. send Intent to main app
   }
  };
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
  registerReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver, filter);
 }
}
```

Comment: So when my screen is off this will work or when my app is off?

Comment: do I still need the PhoneStateListener.java or I can just copy it's code to the MyService.java?

Comment: This will work when app is off and service is running in background and you should copy your PhoneStateListener.java in MyService.java which is having onRecieve() method too.